# How to enable comments on custom entities

Tags: 7, entities, comments

I'm using a contributed module that provides a custom entity. I would like to modify that entity and want to enable comments for this entity.

Does anybody know how to enable commens for custom entities?

Comment: an 'entity' can mean nearly anything - are you referring to a node? a content type? a field?

Comment: It's not a node and not a content type. It is a custom entity. 
You can create own custom entities by implementing hook_entity_info() (see [Creating your own entities with Entity API](http://www.trellon.com/content/blog/creating-own-entities-entity-api) for more details)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to enable comments for custom entities because the structure of comments is made to comment nodes and not entities.

Answer (score 2):

For Drupal 7, this module should do it - https://www.drupal.org/project/comments_entity

For Drupal 8, comments are available as a field for any entity type.

Summary:

1. Create a new Entity Type
2. Create a new Bundle for that Entity Type
3. Create a new Comment Type and select your Entity Type
4. "Manage Fields" on your new Bundle and add a new "Comments" field.
5. Configure comments as desired in the field settings.

Wrote a blog post about it here: http://www.daggerhart.com/drupal-8-add-comments-custom-entity-type/

Comment: That's true for Drupal 8 but not for Drupal 7.

Comment: @seb I see now this is for D7. My mistake. Here is a potential D7 solution - https://www.drupal.org/project/comments_entity